# access to hash through an variable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

Hello I have following problem.

I have a hash filled with the html parameters (params):

```
Parameters:  "info"=>{"parameter2"=>{"r1"=>"aa", "r2"=>"bb", "r3"=>"cc", "r4"=>"dd", "r5"=>"ee"}
```

You can access this values like  this:

`<%= params[:info][:parameter2][:r1] %>` --> it works fine

But I have a loop, and want to access these values through a variable like that:

```
<% for number_row in (1..@numb_rows) %>

<%= params[:info][:parameter2]["r" + number_row.to_s]  %>

<% end %>
```

--> it doesn´t work .
I always get this error :

> can't convert nil into String

But the "r1" does exist. Why it always says, that it can not convert nil into String.

How I can access these params with an changing variable ??

I need something like this :  params[:info][:parameter2][@var]

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby, things with a colon in front of it are a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html). The error you are getting is correct, since you are referencing "r1", instead of :r1.

You need to use `to_sym` to make a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000810) from a [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html).

```
n = "r" + number_row.to_s
params[:info][:parameter2][n.to_sym]
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Thx. 
But unfortunately I get the same error: can't convert nil into String 

Somehow it do not accepts vars:
 n = "r" + "1" --> it works, it can transform it into a symbol
 n = "r" + number_row.to_s --> than he can not transform it into a Symbol

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `.to_s` on `number_row`. Here's a test in irb http://i.imgur.com/JYMTV.png

Comment: Thanks! idk if this is the right way of doing it, but helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very un-ruby. Try

```
params[:info][:parameter2].each do |key, value|
```

...

Comment: the problem is, that in need this in another loop, and I only need one value from this hash

Comment: `value` is the current value of the iteration. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Yes the value is the current value of the iteration. I want to fetch the key-value from that hash. The problem is somehow that what Nate Pinchot explained (see next answer).

Comment: Why do you want external iteration? Most often, Ruby provides better means.

Comment: because I have an different iteration, where I only want to look up the params from that parameter2 .

Answer (score 0):

Try this way !

```
<% params[:info][:parameter2].keys do |key| %>

<%= params[:info][:parameter2][key] %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
1.upto(@numb_rows).each do |i|
  puts params['info']['parameter2']["r#{i}"]}
end
```

Comment: Yes, this works ,if you change that into this:

1.upto(@numb_rows-1) { |i|
         puts  params[:info][:parameter2]["r#{i.to_s}"]}

Thx a lot.

Comment: Glad that helped. And btw, Ruby will implicitly convert the integer to a string. You don't have to call to_s. And do you really want to offset @numb_rows by -1? That will leave out the last row (r5), right?

Comment: I had there somewhere an error, because the range was somehow too big. Than I was testing, if it is work if the @numb_rows max number is minus one. Then it worked fine.
But the main thing is, that your codes works for me :) . Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @wabbiti then you should probably be starting from 0.  `0.upto(@num_rows-1)`.  That way it'll execute @num_rows times.